# Solving a limit using MacLaurin series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I want to find
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{(e^{-x^2}-1)\sin x }{x\ln(1+x^2)}$$
using a Maclaurin series and not using the l'Hôpital's rule.

However I can't seem to get it right.

Thanks for any possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{-x^2}-1=-x^2+o(x^3), x \to 0$

$\ln (1 + x^2)=x^2+o(x^3), x \to 0$

$\sin x = x+o(x^2),  \ x \to 0$

The limit is -1.

Comment: What needs to be added for a rigorous proof such as answering this in a test ?

Comment: That if $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then $\lim f(x) \cdot h(x) = \lim g(x) \cdot h(x)$ and $\lim f(x) + h(x) = \lim g(x) + h(x)$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* When $t\to0$, then $e^t\sim1+t$, and $\ln(1+t)\sim t$. Also, $\dfrac{\sin x}x\to1$ as $x\to0$.